# Right stick doesn't work in any Steam games?

Tags: steam, controllers, windows-10

I have an Xbox One Elite controller and Windows 10. Everything works except the right stick does not move the camera.  I have used the Windows Controller utility to confirm that Windows is receiving the input.

[image]

Not sure if it's related, but I've also noticed in Windows 10 that the left stick scrolls regular windows.  Maybe Windows is getting in the way?

I've tried in both Big Picture and launching it regularly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Solution:** Uncheck "Xbox Configuration Support" in the Controller Config menu in Steam.

---

Recently Steam announced Controller Config support, similar to the Steam Controller profiles, for Xbox controllers.  When this announcement happened, I started playing around with the settings.  I set this:

[image]

I forgot about it.  But that was the problem.  I just disabled it and everything is fine again.

Comment: Perfect. I had a suspicion that something had changed on Steam since nothing else had updated. Opened Big Picture mode earlier and it offered to save my controller settings, which made me a bit weary. Glad I found this answer

Comment: Marked as community wiki in hopes that it can end up at the top since it directly fixes the issue (and this question now has 10k views)

Answer (score 3):

To directly answer - **Windows is *part* of the problem but not the *entirety* of the problem.** Steam isn't really addressing the issue on their end, either. The general fix for it is updating the drivers for the controller manually and making sure you correctly choose which controller is present.

I would *suggest* trying a fresh device install by deleting the drivers, rebooting to save the registry without the device, and then installing the device and drivers from the method below. Windows Registry can be a strange thing sometimes...

The official method to check and update drivers for the XBOX Controllers and Windows 10 is described [here](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-on-windows/accessories/how-to-update-xbox-one-controller-windows-10) as:

> On Windows 10, update your controller by using the Xbox Accessories
>   app:
>
> 1. Get the app from the Windows 10 Store by searching for "Xbox
>      Accessories."
> 2. Launch the Xbox Accessories app.
> 3. Connect your Xbox One Wireless Controller by using a USB cable or
>      the Xbox Wireless Adapter for Windows. **Note:** You'll be prompted to update to Windows 10 Anniversary Edition if you haven't
>      yet done so.
> 4. When the controller is connected, you'll see the message “Update
>      Required” if an update is mandatory.
> 5. Install the update.**Note** You can also go to Device Info to check for updates.
>
> Notes
>
> - The Xbox Accessories app is available only on Windows 10.
> - Controllers that don't have a built-in 3.5-mm audio port must be    updated using a USB connection and must have the Windows 10 TH2
>     Update (or later).
> - Updating the controller over Bluetooth is not supported.
> - Bluetooth requires PCs running the Windows 10 Anniversary Update. See    Windows Update: FAQ to learn how to get the latest Windows
>     update.

If that doesn't seem like much an option for you, a Reddior on [Windows 10 Reddit suggests](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/317s9a/xbox_one_controller_not_working/):

> I got mine to work by doing the following:
>
> - Open Device Manager
> - Right Click "Xbox One Controller"
> - Select Update Driver Software
> - Browse
> - Let me pick
> - "Microsoft Xbox One Controller"
>
> The "Xbox One Controller" driver doesn't work, but the "Microsoft Xbox
>   One Controller" does.

### TL;DR (where and how about the issue)

Ars Technica contributor *Sam Machkovech* posted an [update](http://arstechnica.com/gaming/2016/08/xbox-one-controllers-and-windows-10-pcs-its-all-a-mess-right-now/) on August 10, 2016 that states:

> ...a Microsoft representative confirmed that the Xbox
>   engineering team was working on issues with controllers' "exclusive"
>   modes, controller connectivity with certain games, and Steam Big
>   Picture mode seeing two controllers where there should be only one. No
>   timeline was given for fixes on those issues. The Microsoft rep also
>   insisted that two of the new-hardware Xbox One gamepads should be able
>   to connect simultaneously to a single Windows 10 PC via Bluetooth, so
>   long as both controllers have their firmware updated. The company's
>   support site still lists a one-pad limit when connecting via
>   Bluetooth. We are awaiting a response about that discrepancy.

However, [there are a number of complaints and questions regarding similar issues that still exist](https://forums.xbox.com/en-US/thread/A4902718-271C-4C0A-984E-359E21ED4BA7#5717060) on the Microsoft XBox forum regarding controllers on Steam with no marked solutions as of yet. This is usually pointed to a [SafeFileHandle issue on connected devices after Anniversary Update](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/windows-10-au-1607-no-longer-allows-the-creation/c77fb9a4-d37f-45e4-99c7-6d0880f72833?tm=1470187583342) issue in Windows:

> As of update 1607, kernel32.dll CreateFile() using only the flags
>   GENERIC_READ and GENERIC_WRITE and 0 for dwShareMode no longer allow
>   exclusive (non shared) access to devices needed in some circumstances.
>   An example of a device that is not allowing exclusive access any more
>   is the Sony Dualshock 4 Game controller. Any attempt to connect sets
>   the IsInvalid field for the returned SafeFileHandle.

[Windows Update 3176938](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4001758), released August 31, addressed most of that problem (sloppily). There's a shared responsibility with Microsoft at the foundation but platforms like Steam aren't doing much to push for a solution or change how they handle aspects of input and software developers aren't going back and accounting for evolving hardware.

With regard to Steam, the most updated drivers and patches for games which may address title specific issues are not always present.

To that note you'll want to visit the developer / publisher website of the games you're playing and check to see if newer patches exist which may solve the issue in specific titles while you wait for the general issue to be resolved.

*Namco Bandi* has [a few upset customers](https://steamcommunity.com/app/441380/discussions/0/350541595123008651/?ctp=7#c224446614468909785) over their dismissive approach to the Elite controllers functioning in an unexpected manner while *SquareEnix* has some upset customers using this controller but over a different functional problem. Other developers have been more proactive in the issue but generally the low install base drives overlooking solvency ("low hanging fruit" and all that).

Comment: Thanks for the super detailed response, but I'm not sure this is the issue.  Everything worked fine a couple weeks ago and now only the right stick doesn't work and it's in all games.  I will try changing the drivers though and report back.

Comment: OK. If that doesn't work, see if you can add some more specific details to the question.

Answer (score -1):

I can confirm that turning off Xbox configuration support in big picture mode on Steam is the fix for this problem. I just turned it on last night and forgot about it, then today could not use my right stick at all in games. I came here and remembered I had just done this last night but had not disconnected and reconnected my controller until this morning, switched the settings back to unchecking Xbox controller support and everything works fine again.